# Can predicates and statements function as singular terms?

Tags: logic

My main goal in this post is just to see whether my intuition on predicates and statements is correct when it comes to classical logic.

What I want to know is whether a predicate can function as a singular term and whether a statement can function as a singular term in classical logic.

My intuition tells me that the answer should be yes in both cases.  A statement exists as a unique thing, so it should be a singular term.  And if a predicate was not a unique thing, how is it that we can refer to it and that it is meaningful?

If a predicate cannot function as a singular term, it seems to me that we would not be able to call any predicate a predicate.  For example, take the sentence “Is a predicate” is a predicate.  The beginning of the sentence would be a singular term, and hence we could not call it a predicate, assuming a predicate could not function as a singular term.  So what exactly is a predicate?  I say that it is a concept (or any potential concept that a human could come up with) that could attempt to apply itself to objects.  I also say that a concept is an object of its own because it exists as a unique thing.

However, I began to develop doubts to my hypothesis while reading the article “Classical Logic” in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy that my mom kindly mailed to me.  It says in section 2.4 that “[w]e assume at the outset that all of the categories are disjoint.”  I take one category to be predicates and another category to be singular terms, although I do not see this stated directly.  In section 2.2, it also gives an example of a zero-place predicate---which is just a statement---and that is why I am also beginning to have doubts that a statement is a singular term.

I would be very happy if someone could elucidate this mystery for me.  Thank you very much for your time and attention!

Comment: No in predicate logic. A *term* is a "name": it refers to a singular object: a man, a number. A predicate expresses a property of objects (a unary predicate): to be mortal, to be even, or a relation between objects: to be married with, to be less than.

Comment: You can review the [SEP's entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#BuilBloc) part on *syntax*: "singular terms, linguistic items whose function is to denote a person or object. One-place predicate letters, called “monadic predicate letters”, correspond to linguistic items denoting properties, like “being a man”, “being red”, or “being a prime number”. Two-place predicate letters, called “binary predicate letters”, correspond to linguistic items denoting binary relations, like “is a parent of” or “is greater than”."

Comment: And yes, the two "categories" must be disjoint.

Comment: You concern is about the distinction between "language": the formal expressions **defined** in the SEP's entry, and the "meta-language": the usual English **used** in writing the entry itself and necessary to define and describe the formal language. When we write the sentence '  “Is a predicate” is a predicate' we are speaking in the metalanguage and the predicate "Is a predicate" is not a predicate of the language (they are Px,Qx, etc) but we are using the natural language to describe a common "property" of the expression of the language.

Comment: SEP restricts "classical logic" to first order logic where neither statements nor predicates are objects, for which singular terms are reserved and which are quantified over. When statements and/or predicates are made into objects you get [second order logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/), then one can assign singular terms to them and quantify over them. There are classical second order logics, but plain "classical logic" typically does not refer to them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input!  I am planning to get a good grip on first order logic before I move on to second order logic.  I guess since statements cannot be singular terms in first order logic is why we don't have to consider the liar's paradox in first order logic.